# Before/After charts split by date in slicer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powerbi

I have (SQL Server table) three data series with response times over a time period (min, mean and max). Then I have a SharePoint list with events and dates.

I need a way to show two charts in Power BI, a Before chart and a After chart. The Before chart only shows values before the date selected in a slicer (from the SharePoint list) and the After chart only shows values after that date.

Any ideas to how I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let's say your table you want to split is called `table`.
- Add an additional `date` table and add a slicer with it.
- Add a measure like this:
  `IsBefore = IF((Max('table'[Date])<Min('Date'[Date])),1,0)`
- Add your two charts, filter first by `IsBefore = 1` and second - by `IsBefore = 0`
- Voila!
  [image]

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much :).